# How to (unsafely) reflect a map as a constraint?

Tags: dictionary, haskell, reflection, typeclass, singleton-type

I want a typeclass that represents membership in a *reified* `Data.Map.Map`. So something like:

```
class Reifies s (Map Text v) => IsMember (x :: Symbol) s where
  value :: Proxy s -> Proxy x -> v
```

And then I would like to implement a function which returns a `Dict` instance of this class whenever a symbol is present:

```
checkMember :: forall s x v. (KnownSymbol x, Reifies s (Map Text v))
  => proxy x -> Maybe (Dict (IsMember x s))
checkMember sx =
  let m = reflect (Proxy @s)
  in  (_ :: v -> Dict (IsMember x s)) <$> Map.lookup (symbolVal sx) m
```

I don't mind using `unsafeCoerce` to implement `checkMember`, but even so I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this (fill in the type hole).

---

Approximate preamble:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Constraint(Dict(..))
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))
import Data.Reflection (Reifies, reflect)
import GHC.TypeLits (KnownSymbol, Symbol, symbolVal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does it have to be a class `IsMember`? How about a simple type:

```
newtype Member x s v = Member v

checkMember :: ... => proxy x -> Maybe (Member x s v)
```

Keeping `Member` abstract allows to preserve the invariant that a value of type `Member x s v` belongs to the dictionary associated with `s`. No `unsafeCoerce` on your part are needed.

From there, there might also be some way to use reflection to lift `Member` back to the type level but that sounds overengineered.

---

**EDIT:** from the discussion, it seems the requirement is external and there isn't much to do about it. Here is a way to implement `checkMember`.

(`reflection` implements its own machinery like this too.)

We can abuse the fact that GHC desugars classes with a single method and no superclasses `class C a where m :: v` directly to the unwrapped method `m :: v`, and constrained values `C a => b` to functions `v -> b`.

- we need a version of `IsMember` without superclasses (`IsMember0`)
- we wrap `IsMember0 x s v => r` in a newtype so it can be coerced to `IsMember0 x s v -> r` (`UnsafeMember`)

---

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Constraint(Dict(..))
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))
import Data.Reflection (Reifies, reflect, reify)
import GHC.TypeLits (KnownSymbol, Symbol, symbolVal)
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)

type Text = String

class IsMember0 (x :: Symbol) s v | s -> v where
  value0 :: Proxy s -> Proxy x -> v

class (Reifies s (Map Text v), IsMember0 x s v) => IsMember (x :: Symbol) s v | s -> v
instance (Reifies s (Map Text v), IsMember0 x s v) => IsMember (x :: Symbol) s v

value :: IsMember x s v => Proxy s -> Proxy x -> v
value = value0

newtype UnsafeMember x s v = UnsafeMember (IsMember0 x s v => Dict (IsMember x s v))

unsafeMember :: forall x s v. Reifies s (Map Text v) => v -> Dict (IsMember x s v)
unsafeMember v = unsafeCoerce (UnsafeMember @x @s @v Dict) (\ _ _ -> v)

checkMember :: forall s x v proxys proxyx. (KnownSymbol x, Reifies s (Map Text v))
  => proxys s -> proxyx x -> Maybe (Dict (IsMember x s v))
checkMember _ sx =
  let m = reflect (Proxy @s)
  in  unsafeMember <$> Map.lookup (symbolVal sx) m

-- Executable example
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let d = Map.fromList [("foo", 33 :: Int)]
      foo = Proxy :: Proxy "foo"
  reify d (\p ->
    case checkMember p foo of
      Nothing -> fail "Not found"
      Just Dict -> print (value0 p foo))
```

Comment: It needs to be a class because I'm using it as a constraint for an instance of another class which is defined elsewhere and I can't make changes to.

Comment: It's the same reason `reflection` exists in the first place. Because sometimes we need to feed arguments into classes rather than into methods.

Comment: @dspyz Perhaps you could convert a term-level string to `SomeSymbol` with `someSymbolVal` and then pattern-match on the result http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:someSymbolVal